# Could not load file or assembly ServiceRuntime 2.4.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net, azure-service-runtime

After upgrading our project to use the Azure SDK 2.5, I get the following runtime exception when deployed to Azure (web role):

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

One of the referenced packages from NuGet is still referencing `ServiceRuntime 2.4.0.0`. From what I understand, all I need to do to fix this is create a `bindingRedirect` in our `web.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  The exception persists.  Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After upgrading to SDK 2.5 myself i had the same problem you have now. I went trough all of the projects in the solution, and checked all of the references to **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime**. Remove them, and add them again using the **Add Reference** option. Select the assembly again, however make sure it is the 2.5.0.0 version. Rebuild and redeploy. Things should work again now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting the Copy Local property to True for the referenced assembly fixed this.

1. In Solution Explorer find your project's reference to the library.
2. Right click and choose Properties
3. In the Properties window set Copy Local to True